# node.js serialport cannot pass variable outside SerialPort.list function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, node-serialport

I am trying to get the **COM port** of my device at runtime using the node.js serialport module.

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
var fs = require('fs');

var serialVar = getSerialPort();

console.log("outer: "+serialVar);

function getSerialPort() 
{
    SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
        ports.forEach(function(port) {
            if (port.pnpId == "USB\\VID_0451&PID_BEF3&MI_00\\6&808E38E&0&0000") {
                console.log("inner: "+port.comName);
                return port.comName;
            } 
        });
    });
}
```

output:

```
outer: undefined
inner: COM8
```

From the output, it appears that `getSerialPort()` finishes after everything else in the script has run rather than running in it's entirety before continuing past the point it was called. I'm not sure why this is.

I have tried several variations of this such as:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
var fs = require('fs');

var serialVar = {};
getSerialPort();

console.log("outer: "+serialVar.port);
function getSerialPort() 
{
    SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
        ports.forEach(function(port) {
            if (port.pnpId == "USB\\VID_0451&PID_BEF3&MI_00\\6&808E38E&0&0000") {
                serialVar.port = port.comName;
                console.log("inner: "+serialVar.port);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

with no change.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is inherently asynchronous. What is happening is that the `console.log` is executing before the serial ports can be listed. The library provides a callback (which you are using) and a promise. Either of these can be used to make sure things run in order. I recommend promises.

```js
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

SerialPort.list() // returns promise that resolves to list of ports
    // filters for a specific port
    .then(ports => ports.filter(port => port.pnpId == "USB\\VID_0451&PID_BEF3&MI_00\\6&808E38E&0&0000"))
    // logs info
    .then(ports => {console.log('inner',port[0].comName, 'outer', port[0]); return ports})
```